# Adding point into Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im in need for some help. I need to create a code that ads points into my circle and provides a dropdown bar.
This is my code so far for creating the sircle.

```
   var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var punkter = []; // List over all the points.
    var antall = 16 ++; // Number of points the sircle should have .
    var step = 2 * Math.PI / antall; // Angle ran between each point.
    var r = 300; // The radius of the circle.
    var v = 0; // The angle of the circle.

    //----- Background ------
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,800,800);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffd083";
    ctx.fill();

    function calculate() {
        //Calculates all the points
        for (var i = 0; i < antall; i++) { // i = []
            var x = 400 + r * Math.cos(v); //Placement
            var y = 400 + r * Math.sin(v); //Placement
            punkter[i] = new Point(x, y);
            v += step; // For each point, the angle changes.
        }


    }

    function draw() {
        //Drawing the sircle
        ctx.beginPath(); // Starting a line.
        ctx.moveTo(punkter[0].x, punkter[0].y); // Draws line from one point to a new one.
        for (var i = 1; i < antall; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(punkter[i].x, punkter[i].y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

    }

    function Point(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    calculate();
    draw();
```

[picture one show the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1prF.png)

[this is what I'm aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYLuJ.png)

So the point is to create a circle in which you can add draw points and change the point on which they are drawn (i think).

And as you can see I'm pretty new in coding.

Comment: You should probably have the comments in English, if you want us to understand them

Comment: Changed them now, thanks for the tip

Comment: I also suggest you to build a codepen (https://codepen.io/), to show better your case: